# Limit of a function ("order of magnitude")

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

Find $f(x)$ (in terms of exponentials) such that $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{-\cosh\frac{1}{x}}}{f(x)}=A$$ where $A\in\mathbb{R}, A\neq0$

I have tried calculating Maclaurin series but I get zeroes everywhere, like $e^{-cosh\frac{1}{x}}$ is not analytic. I don't know what else to try!

Comment: What do you mean by 'in terms of exponentials'?

Comment: In terms of the exponential function like if our numerator was $sinh\frac{1}{x}$ we would get $f(x)=e^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Comment: I still don't get what exactly your criterion on $f$ is because obviously $f(x)= \tfrac 1A \exp(-\cosh(\tfrac 1x))$ would be a trivial example of such a function $f$. But I guess it's not this one you are interested in...

Comment: That example is probably too trivial. I think I would be looking for a single exponential in the solution. Not exponential of an exponential (as in $exp(cosh x)$)

Comment: But this is kinda like asking to give a rational function that is asymptotic to $e^y$ as  $y\to \infty$, which is impossible.

Comment: @pilgrim Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\cosh\frac{1}{x}=\frac{e^{\frac1x}+e^{-\frac1x}}{2}=\frac12e^{\left|\frac1x\right|}+\frac12e^{-\left|\frac1x\right|}  $$

thus

$$e^{-\cosh\frac{1}{x}}= e^{\frac12e^{\left|\frac1x\right|}+\frac12e^{-\left|\frac1x\right|}}= e^{\frac12e^{\left|\frac1x\right|}} e^{ \frac12e^{-\left|\frac1x\right|}}\sim e^{\frac12e^{\left|\frac1x\right|}}$$

and

$$f(x)= e^{-\frac12e^{\left|\frac1x\right|}}\implies \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{-\cosh\frac{1}{x}}}{f(x)}=1$$

Comment: Your limit works for $x \to 0^+$, but not $x \to 0$. Further, $a \sim b$ does not imply $e^a \sim e^b$.

Comment: @AntonioVargasthanks for your observation, I'll try to fix it!

Comment: @AntonioVargas does it work now?

Comment: You still use the **false** implication $a \sim b \implies e^a \sim e^b$. So your argument is still flawed.

Comment: @AntonioVargas What about the new one?

Comment: Your solution of $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}e^{|\frac{1}{x}|}}$ gives a limit of zero but we require $A\neq0$.

Comment: @pilgrim the limit should be 1

Comment: @gimusi the limit is 1, I entered in into the graph plotter incorrectly and got 0.

Comment: @pilgrim thus do you think that this f(x) can work?

Comment: @gimusi I think your solution is a possible function f(x), since the limit is 1, which is allowed.

Comment: Looks good now.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thanks a lot for your valuable help and advices!